# Match beginning of words from a character array?

Tags: regex

I would like to use regex to match the beginnings of words in a string given a set of characters.

Consider this:

```
string = "abcd ab def"
match = ["a", "b", "d"]
```

From that, I want it to match `ab` in `abcd` and `d` in `def` but NOT `ab` in `ab` for the simple reason that we already had a match beginning with `a`.

I tried the following:

```
/(\babd)|(\bab)|(\ba)|(\bbd)|(\bb)|(\bd)/gi
```

which sort of works, except for the fact that `ab` also gets matched. I understand WHY it gets matched, and it should, given my regex. However, I don't know how to make it match words beginning with `a` only once.

Basically, what I want is that given the characters `abd`, I want a match for the FIRST word beginning with `a` and also whether it also matches `ab` and/or `abd`. After that I want only the first match for words beginning with `b` and whether or not that also matches with `bd`. Finally, I want the first match for words beginning with `d`.

It would be quite easy to just iterate over the matches and only keep the first of matches for any given character, but I would much rather solve it directly in the regex.

To make it extra fun, consider this:

```
string = "abcd ab def bd"
match = ["a", "b", "d"]
```

This also matches `bd`, but I don't want that since the `b` in `abd` was "used up" in the first match.

How to solve this?

Comment: ab matches because of `(\bab)` regex. Why you don't want to match `d` in the first `abcd` string?

Comment: Yes, I know, but basically what I want to be able to do is filter a list of names based on an array of characters.

After `ab` matches in `abcd` I want the characters `a` and `b` in `abd` to be considered used and not valid for further matches.

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for this, then. I have updated my answer to show a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if your regex engine support indefinite repetition inside [lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), so you're pretty much limited to the .NET or JGSoft engines:

```
(?<!\b\1.*)\b(ab|d)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!    # Make sure it's impossible to match *before* the current position
 \b     # the start of a word
 \1     # and the match of the capturing group 1
 .*     # followed by any number of characters
)       # End of lookbehind assertion
\b      # Match a start of a word
(ab|d)  # Match (and capture in group 1) either "ab" or "d"
```

**Edit:**

Since you now have specified your language as Java, a regex solution won't work. And your second case is impossible to implement with a regex since the regex engine doesn't keep state across individual regex matches anyway, so there is no way to prevent `bd` from matching. You need a programmatic solution, which fortunately is rather trivial. I'm not a Java person, but the following Python script should be quite readable:

```
string = "abcd ab def bd"
match = {"a", "b", "d"}   # Set of all characters to be considered
words = string.split()    # Split string on whitespace
result = []
for word in words:        # Python's for is like Java's foreach
    add = False
    for letter in word:
        if letter in match:
            add = True
            match.remove(letter)
        else:
            break
    if add:
        result.append(word)
```

`result` is `['abcd', 'def']`.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising!
I'm using Java, which I believe supports lookbehind.

However, I'm getting a `Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 9` error. Any ideas?

Also, how would I expand this if the matching string is longer? E.g. `abdef`?

Comment: Don't think Java supports variable length lookbehinds.

Comment: @tenub: Yes, it doesn't. That's why a regex question should always be tagged with the pertinent language.

Comment: Thank you! I've marked this as the correct answer. If you hadn't told me that it's impossible in java, I probably would have kept trying indefinitely.